# Can't inserting data into database

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to inserting data into database but, I am failing to do it. I have tried ample of videos and internet surf but not successful. My code is following I have created controller and passing request from controller it is not accepting.

```
<form action="/StudentInsert" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="txtFname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
                        <input type="text" name="txtLname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="txtContact" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact">
                        <input type="text" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

this is my controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StudInsertController extends Controller
{
    //Insert Form
    public function StudentInsertForm()
    {
        return view('StudInsert');
    }
    public function StudentInsert(Request $request)
    {
        $first_name = $request->input('txtFname');
        $last_name = $request->input('txtLname');
        $contact = $request->input('txtContact');
        $email = $request->input('txtEmail');
        $data = array('first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'contact' => $contact, 'email' => $email);
        DB::table('student')->insert($data);
        echo "Record inserted Successfully.<br/>";
        echo '<a href="/StudView">Click Here</a>';
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
 */

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('StudInsert');
});
Route::get('StudentInsertForm', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsertForm');
Route::get('StudentInsert', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsert');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the post route instead of get in web.php file to retrieve post data like this

```
Route::post('StudentInsert', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsert');
```

Replace below line in web.php

```
Route::get('StudentInsert', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsert');
```

with this new one

```
Route::post('StudentInsert', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsert');
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be great you provide the exact error you are getting.
But I can see a couple of bugs already.
You are trying to send a post request to your Laravel app from you form, but in your routes list you are not waiting for any post request.

You can do following:

- Make sure you are accepting post request in your `web.php`:

```
Route::post('StudentInsert', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentInsertController@StudentInsert');
```

- Also Laravel by default requires CSRF token in any form posted. So your form should look like this:

```
<form action="/StudentInsert" method="post">
    @csrf   
    <!-- Equivalent to... -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="txtFname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
                <input type="text" name="txtLname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="txtContact" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact">
                <input type="text" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
             <p>
                <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

More details in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf)

I would also recommend using [Laravel form helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)